# In Gauss integer integral domain, $p$ is prime iff the equation $x^2+y^2=p$ has no solution

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

In Gauss integer integral domain $G= \mathbb Z[i]$, if p is prime integer then $p$ is prime in $\mathbb Z[i]$ iff the equation $x^2+y^2=p$ has no solution in $\mathbb Z$.

the first side is easy, if $p$ is prime, suppose $x^2+y^2=p$ has a solution then

$(x+iy)(x-iy)=x^2+y^2=p$ where either $x+iy$ is a unit or $x-iy$ is a unit

$\Rightarrow$ either      $ x=\pm1$  and $  y=0,$ or $x=0$ and $y=\pm1$

This makes the equation $p=x^2+y^2=1$ and that's a contradiction.

the other side is harder. I thought of using contrapositive ( if $p$ is composite then $x^2+y^2=p$ has a solution in $\mathbb Z$)  but I couldn't reach something.

Comment: Did you mean *Gauss* where you typed *Guess*?

Comment: oh yes! my bad, it must be the autocorrect

Comment: Surely the nature of the primes in the Gaussians has been discussed many times on this site. Might do well to search for a previous occurence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the contrapositve.
Let $p$ be prime integer but not prime in $\mathbb Z[i]$

so that $p$ can be written as product of 2 non invertible elements in $\mathbb Z[i]$ i.e

$p =\alpha \beta$

taking the norm for both sides

$N(p) = N(\alpha) N(\beta) = p^2$

Now since the norms are integers and neither $\alpha $ nor $\beta$ are units then $N(\alpha) =p$

Let $\alpha = x+iy$ , for some $x,y \in \mathbb Z$

$N(\alpha) = x^2+y^2= p$

so the equation $x^2+y^2= p$ has a solution